# Write a function(s) that subsets a dataframe by removing rows that are WITHIN the InterQuartile Region of a specified column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the complete question:

Write a function(s) that subsets a dataframe by removing rows that are WITHIN the InterQuartile Region of a specified column.

The function takes as input:

A: Pandas_Dataframe (For example use NHL_GoaliesDF)

B. Column name¶

Expected Output:

A. The output is a DataFrame that removes rows outside of the specified columns IQR.

So here is what I have so far:

```
NHL_Goalies= 
pd.read_excel('NHLGoalies2016_2017.xls',na_values='',sheetname=0) 

import pandas as pd
def pandas_filter():
    df= NHL_Goalies
    column= "Ht"
    q1 = df[column].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df[column].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = (df[column] <= q1) | (df[column] >= q3)
    return df[iqr]

pandas_filter()
```

The above function works perfectly fine and prints out what the question asks. However, if I incorporate the user input for the df and column variables I get the following:

```
def pandas_filter():
   df= input()
   column= input()
   q1 = df[column].quantile(0.25)
   q3 = df[column].quantile(0.75)
   iqr = (df[column] <= q1) | (df[column] >= q3)
   return df[iqr]

pandas_filter()
```

---

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b7d8feaf055e> in <module>()
  7     return df[iqr]
  8 
----> 9 pandas_filter()

<ipython-input-17-b7d8feaf055e> in pandas_filter()
  2     df= input()
  3     column= input()
----> 4     q1 = df[column].quantile(0.25)
  5     q3 = df[column].quantile(0.75)
  6     iqr = (df[column] <= q1) | (df[column] >= q3)

TypeError: string indices must be integer
```

The question now is how do I go about this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because `df` overwrite to be an input in the second function...

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @U9-Forward means that you have to delete the line `df= input()` from your code, as that is overwriting the entire DataFrame with whatever string the user types in.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, the question is asking to let the user input the dataframe name(which in this case, for example NHL_Goalies) and also input the column that needs to be filtered.

Comment: @BVG One thing should be changed is the variable name for the input, the you have to write the code to read the csv

Comment: thank you, i figured it out. I